# Error function not executing correctly

Tags: c

I seem to have an issue with my code, the code works but not as intended. The idea is the program reads a data file named `data.txt`, each line is read and the line has its own element separated by a `:` token.

The code reads this, stores the data within a variable, and then compares it to my validation specification, the program then does post all the correct lines which have passed validation to the `data.txt` file, but nothing is posted inside the `error.txt` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used

struct packet{
    int source;        // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int destination;   // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int type;          // 0 - 10 range (int)               // Varibles for the         structure
    int port;          // 1 = 1024 (int)
    char data[50];     // 1 - 50 range (char)

};

int main()
{

    char filename[32] = { '\0' } ;   // variables which declare the I/O stream and the filename structure
    char DataLine[75];               // Reads the file one line at a time
    char ErrorLine[75];              // This is the varible that deals with the validation error
    char TempStorage[5];                // Stores data to be validated
    char TempData[50];                   // Stores the data which will be validated
    int  TempS, TempD, TempT, TempP;  // Stores the integer derived from the input file
    int  Flag = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicates a Line has not passed validation
    int  Count = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicated a line has passed validation
    int  Ecount = 0;                  // This counts the number of errors
    char *ptr;
    char *token;
    const char s[4] = ":";

struct packet *DataRecords;
DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));    // This deals with storing the data needed for the next task.

                                                              // The program must prompt for the name of the input file. If it doesn't exist the program should stop with an error message

 printf("Enter the filename you wish to open\n");
 scanf("%s", &filename);
                                      // user inputs the filename
FILE *DataFile;
if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
     printf ("\nfile could not be opened. : %s\n", filename);  // If a value of NULL is returned then the program will close.

}
else
{
```

Where the error is possibly occurring:

```
FILE *ErrorFile = fopen("error.txt","w");                         // This will start searching through the lines and store the lines not passing the validation test to a txt file named "error.txt".
printf("File has been found, checking validation");

  while( fgets (DataLine, 75, DataFile)!=NULL) {
    strcpy(ErrorLine, DataLine);

    strcpy(TempStorage, token = strtok(DataLine, s));
    TempS = strtol (TempStorage, NULL, 10);

    strcpy(TempStorage, token = strtok(NULL, s));           // these lines of code looks through each line and stores the line within the "Temp Storage" variable, the : token is what the element within the line is seperated by.
    TempD = strtol (TempStorage, NULL, 10);

    strcpy(TempStorage, token = strtok(NULL, s));
    TempT = strtol (TempStorage, NULL, 10);

    strcpy(TempStorage, token = strtok(NULL, s));
    TempP = strtol (TempStorage, NULL, 10);

    strcpy(TempData, strtok( NULL, ":"));
    strncpy(TempStorage, TempData, 50);                   // security details 

        if (TempS < 1 || TempS > 1024) Flag = 1;
        if (TempD < 1 || TempD > 1024) Flag = 1;
        if (TempT < 0 || TempT > 10) Flag = 1;                   // // Validation aspect, if the validation is not met then a flag is added to which then the line is posted within the error file.
        if (TempP < 1 || TempP > 1024) Flag = 1;
        if (strlen(TempData) < 1 || strlen(TempData)> 50) Flag = 1;

        if (Flag == 1)
        {
            printf("Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s",Ecount,TempS,TempD,TempT,TempP,TempData);
            Ecount++;
            fprintf(ErrorFile,"%s", ErrorLine);
            // fprintf writes formatted text to the output stream you specify
        }
        else
        {
            DataRecords[Count].source = TempS;
            DataRecords[Count].destination = TempD;
            DataRecords[Count].type = TempT;
            DataRecords[Count].port = TempP;
            strncpy(DataRecords[Count].data,TempData,51);
            Count++; //increment sequence number
            DataRecords = realloc(DataRecords,(Count+1)*sizeof(struct packet));//allocate more memory for packet data
        }
Flag = 0;
}
FILE *DFile = fopen("data.txt","w");
int i;
for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    fprintf(DFile,  "%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s",DataRecords[i].source,    // Where the data that has passed validation goes
    DataRecords[i].destination,
    DataRecords[i].type,
    DataRecords[i].port,
    DataRecords[i].data);
      }
    fclose(DFile);
    fclose(DataFile);
    fclose(ErrorFile);
    printf("\nNumber of errors: %i \n", Ecount);
    printf("Number of saved records: %i ", Count);
    free(DataRecords);

}
return 0;
}
```

Here is what the data looks like within the `data.txt` file:

```
1025:2222:1231:1312:0000
0002:0004:0002:0090:100000000000000000022
0001:0002:0003:0021:DEL
0002:0004:0002:0010:100000000000000000023
0001:0002:0002:0080:PAGE 1<BR>
0003:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000026
0004:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000027
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to narrow down the code, for example by stepping though it line by line in a debugger. Also, please provide the *expected* and *actual* output.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &filename);` should be `scanf("%s", filename);`

Comment: I have narrowed down where the issue could be, but there is no output within the error.txt file when there should be so I can't really provide anything in regards to that. but I guess the actual output should really be the line itself just copied into the error.txt file

Comment: I debugged the code, it does hold the Struc as intended but the printf("Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s",Ecount,TempS,TempD,TempT,TempP,TempData); line does not seem to execute it

Comment: The flag value is fine, I checked that during the debugging proccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem appears to be `strncpy(TempStorage, TempData, 50);` as TempStorage was declared with [5] and the strncpy using 50 overwrites TempStorage, corrupting adjacent variables.
This uses sscanf to extract the values from the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used

struct packet{
    int source;        // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int destination;   // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int type;          // 0 - 10 range (int)               // Varibles for the         structure
    int port;          // 1 = 1024 (int)
    char data[50];     // 1 - 50 range (char)
};

int main()
{
    char filename[32] = { '\0' } ;   // variables which declare the I/O stream and the filename structure
    char DataLine[75];               // Reads the file one line at a time
    char ErrorLine[75];              // This is the varible that deals with the validation error
    char TempStorage[5];                // Stores data to be validated
    char TempData[50];                   // Stores the data which will be validated
    int  TempS, TempD, TempT, TempP;  // Stores the integer derived from the input file
    int  Flag = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicates a Line has not passed validation
    int  Count = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicated a line has passed validation
    int  Ecount = 0;                  // This counts the number of errors
    char *ptr;
    char *token;
    const char s[4] = ":";
    struct packet *DataRecords;
    DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));    // This deals with storing the data needed for the next task.
    // The program must prompt for the name of the input file. If it doesn't exist the program should stop with an error message
    printf("Enter the filename you wish to open\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    // user inputs the filename
    FILE *DataFile;
    if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nfile could not be opened. : %s\n", filename);  // If a value of NULL is returned then the program will close.
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *ErrorFile = fopen("error.txt","w");                         // This will start searching through the lines and store the lines not passing the validation test to a txt file named "error.txt".
        if ( ErrorFile == NULL) {
            printf ( "Could not open error file\n");
            return 2;
        }
        printf("File has been found, checking validation\n");

        while( fgets (DataLine, 75, DataFile)!=NULL) {
            strcpy(ErrorLine, DataLine);

            sscanf ( DataLine, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%49[^\n]"
            , &TempS
            , &TempD
            , &TempT
            , &TempP
            , TempData);
            if (TempS < 1 || TempS > 1024) {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            if (TempD < 1 || TempD > 1024) {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            if (TempT < 0 || TempT > 10) {
                Flag = 1;                   // // Validation aspect, if the validation is not met then a flag is added to which then the line is posted within the error file.
            }
            if (TempP < 1 || TempP > 1024) {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            if (strlen(TempData) < 1 || strlen(TempData)> 50) {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            if (Flag == 1)
            {
                printf("Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s",Ecount,TempS,TempD,TempT,TempP,TempData);
                Ecount++;
                fprintf(ErrorFile,"%s", ErrorLine);
                // fprintf writes formatted text to the output stream you specify
            }
            else
            {
                DataRecords[Count].source = TempS;
                DataRecords[Count].destination = TempD;
                DataRecords[Count].type = TempT;
                DataRecords[Count].port = TempP;
                strncpy(DataRecords[Count].data,TempData,51);
                Count++; //increment sequence number
                DataRecords = realloc(DataRecords,(Count+1)*sizeof(struct packet));//allocate more memory for packet data
            }
            Flag = 0;
        }
        FILE *DFile = fopen("data.txt","w");
        if ( DFile == NULL) {
            printf ( "Could not open data file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            fprintf(DFile,  "%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s",DataRecords[i].source,    // Where the data that has passed validation goes
            DataRecords[i].destination,
            DataRecords[i].type,
            DataRecords[i].port,
            DataRecords[i].data);
        }
        fclose(DFile);
        fclose(DataFile);
        fclose(ErrorFile);
        printf("\nNumber of errors: %i \n", Ecount);
        printf("Number of saved records: %i ", Count);
        free(DataRecords);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, but the error.txt file which is outputed is still empty even though it outputs the invalid line on the program correctly so it obviously sees it but as mentioned doesn't output it within the text file itself.

Comment: ahh, that seeemed to have worked. Much appreciated, so I guess that line of code was not needed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is posted because you don't get the filename properly.

Change

```
scanf("%s", &filename); /* %s expects a pointer, filename is already a pointer */
```

to

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to be the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    char filename[32] = { '\0' } ; 
    ...
    scanf("%s", &filename);
```

In `scanf()`, `&filename` is incorrect as `filename` is base address of char array of 32 elements. Following `fopen()` on address of address of `filename` is incorrect too. Rather you should read into base address of array pointing to filename as `scanf("%s", filename);`

`const char s[4] = ":";` The delimiter here `s` need not be array of 4 chars as you are trying to delimit at each `:` only. So its good if you have `const char *s = ":";`